# How to change font for Puppeteer Sharp in C#

Tags: fonts, azure-functions, puppeteer-sharp

I am using Puppeteer Sharp in C# which is deployed to Azure Linux Function.
I mentioned `font-family` in html page.
How can I print PDF by using target font, e.g. Roboto font?

Below may be possible solutions but I don't know how to perform or whether available below:

1. Change PDF font by using PuppeteerSharp's API (I could not find this)
2. Install target font in Azure Linux Function

---

Supplement:
I would like to print out different languages on a page but it cannot print such characters.

[image]

Comment: Can't you take the font from a CDN?

Comment: Hi @hardkoded, Sorry for late reply. How can I take/setup fonts form CDN for Azure Linux Function? May you have some guideline for help? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically inject some `html` code and replace the font from a CDN. You can wire a custom solution by combining these two.

- [Inject HTML API] (https://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/index.html#inject-html)
- [Replace CDN](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/issues/1510#issuecomment-766180826)

Comment: Hi @HariHaran, Sorry for late reply. How can I take/setup fonts form CDN for Azure Linux Function? May you have some guideline for help? thanks.